# Run Apache HTTPD as process without window

Tags: java, windows, apache, process

I need to start apache with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("httpd.exe")
```

But I don't want the window, how can I do? With java process I just set javaw instead of java, but how can i do with apache?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe install Apache as service and start/stop it using sc.exe ?

Comment: I would like to run it as a process...

Comment: And it requires to be administrator.